# Collection<Double> to DoubleStream

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I'm looking for most elegant way to create `DoubleStream` (for using sum, average, etc.) from a `List<Double>`. At the moment I have such code:

```
List<Double> doubles = getListOfDoubles();
double sum = doubles.stream()
                    .mapToDouble(d -> d)
                    .sum();
```

Maybe anyone could suggest a shorter way?

Comment: I mean, we have overloaded Arrays.toStream(...) that could return different Streams, so why there is nothing similar for Collections?

Comment: Where is there something like this in `Arrays`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic [Arrays javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

    `static DoubleStream stream(double[] array)
    Returns a sequential DoubleStream with the specified array as its source.`

Similar for IntStream, LongStream

P.S. Sorry for formatting

Comment: But that takes an array of `double` (the primitive), not an array of `Double`. And that's the difference from `Collections`.

Comment: A side note: You might have found the [DoubleStream#boxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#boxed--) method, which basically converts a `DoubleStream` to a `Stream<Double>`. Just in case you wonder why there is no similar `unboxed` method: For the reverse direction, you have to **care for the case that one of the `Double` objects in the input is `null`**.

Comment: @Marco13: `mapToDouble` *is* the unbox method. That’s the only way to provide such functionality on a *generic* `Stream`. You have to specify which of the three alternatives (`IntStream`, `LongStream` or `DoubleStream`) to produce and you have to specify a function that can convert the element type, not known to the stream at runtime, to the target type. That’s exactly what `mapToDouble(ToDoubleFunction)` offers.

Comment: It is not a specific "unboxing" method, but a generic method of mapping *anything* to `double` (and its counterpart is `DoubleStream#mapToObj`). But I guess that's clear.

Comment: @Marco13: there is no reason why a method can’t fulfill two purposes. It’s the canonical unboxing method *and* a way of mapping anything to double. `DoubleStream.boxed()` is just a convenience method for `mapToObj(Double::valueOf)` anyway…

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The best way to obtain statistics from a `Stream` is to use the `...SummaryStatistics` classes. For a `Stream<Double>`, this is [`DoubleSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html):

```
List<Double> doubles = getListOfDoubles();
DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = doubles.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(Double::doubleValue));
System.out.println(stats.getAverage());
System.out.println(stats.getSum());
```

It is obtained by collecting the stream with the [`summarizingDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summarizingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) collector. This collector takes a `ToDoubleFunction` as argument: it is a function which should return the `double` to analyze.

Such statistics can be obtained for [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html), [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LongSummaryStatistics.html) and [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html) values.

Note that the general case of converting a `Collection<Double>` to a `DoubleStream` can be done with the code you already have:

```
List<Double> doubles = getListOfDoubles();
DoubleStream stream = doubles.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do (even it's not significantly shorter, but...):

```
double sum = doubles.stream().collect(Collectors.summingDouble(x -> x));
```

or

```
double sum = DoubleStream.of(doubles.stream().mapToDouble(x->x).toArray()).sum();
```

but the latter is more or less the same as your approach.

Comment: Not really. Storing the entire stream into an intermediate array is a waste of resources without any advantage over all other solutions shown here.